# How to work out the -(-(-(.... part in this code snippet?

Tags: python, braces

I am not looking for the answer for this code, but I would like to know how to do the working out in the `-(-(-(-2))) ...` part.

I tried looking it up on Google `"Python negative braces.."` etc etc but nothing.

```
-(-(-(-2))) == -2 and 4 >= 16 ** 0.5
```

Comment: I don't understand. Are you asking what `-(-(-(-2)))` means?

Comment: The parentheses are completely redundant in this case.  You can simply remove them.

Comment: Also note that `4 >= 16 ** 0.5` has a result that is hard to predict, since floating point results are rounded. While the square root of a perfect square that can be represented exactly will always be represented exactly for implementations following the IEEE-754 standard, it's still generally a mistake to compare floating point numbers for exact equality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What this means is essentially `negative negative negative negative 2`. So because a negative of a negative a positive, this is equal to positive 2.

So in the end: `-(-(-(-2))) == -2` is `False`, so if you include that as part of an `and`, you will get `False` no matter what:

```
>>> -(-(-(-2))) == -2 and True
False
```

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated :D

Answer (score 2):

That works exactly the same way it would in ordinary mathematical notation. `-(anything)` is the negation of whatever is in the parentheses. The negation of 2 is -2, and the negation of -2 is 2.

-(-2) is the negation of -2, which is 2.

-(-(-2)) is the negation of -(-2). -(-2) is 2, and the negation of that is -2.

-(-(-(-2))) is the negation of -(-(-2)). -(-(-2)) is -2, and the negation of that is 2.